# I'm working on pagination in our project using codeigniter framework,i want to display 20 products/page but now i can display 1product/page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on pagination in our project using codeigniter framework,i want to display 20 products/page but now i can display 1product/page.I tried by changing in code $config["per_page"] =1; to $config["per_page"] =20; but it is displaying 1product/page with few products, not all.My code is below

in my view page:

```
<div class="container">        
      <?php  $chunkedArray  = array_chunk($results, 4);
       foreach($chunkedArray as $newRow) {
       echo ' <div class="row section">';?>
  <?php
    foreach ($newRow as $display) {
?>
          <div class="col-md-3 product-display">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/productdisplay_controller/productImage?id=<?php echo $display->id; ?>">
              <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.$display->product_image; ?>" class="img-responsive image" />
              </a>

        <div class="imgage-description">
            <a href="#" title="<?php echo $display->product_name; ?>"><b><p><?php echo $display->product_name; ?></p></b></a> 
                <div class="stitle"> 
                    <a data-p4plog="60491438452" data-domdot="id:2679,pid:60491438452,ext:'n=1|s=p|t={{attr target}}'" href="//gesac.en.alibaba.com/company_profile.html#top-nav-bar" target="_blank">eletronics pvt ltd</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pmo"> 
                    <div class="price"> <b class=""> US $1-1000 </b> / Piece </div> 
                    <div class="min-order"> <b>10 Pieces</b> (Min. Order) </div> 
                </div>
              <a href="<?php  echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/contact"> 
                  <button class="desc-btn" title="Contact Supplier"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Supplier</button> 
              </a>
              </div>
          </div>

          <?php
    }?>
            <?php
    echo '</div> ';
}
    ?>

  </div>
     <div class="center">
    <ul class = "pagination">
    <?php foreach ($links as $link) {
echo "<li>". $link."</li>";
} ?>
</ul>
   </div>
```

my model page:

```
<?php
class homemodel extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

public function record_count() {
return $this->db->count_all("product_sub_category3");
}



// Fetch data according to per_page limit.
public function fetch_data($limit, $id) {
$this->db->limit($limit);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get("product_sub_category3");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
$data[] = $row;
}

return $data;
}
return false;
}

/*public function fetchData() {

  $query=$this->db->select('*');   
  $this->db->order_by('product_name','RANDOM');
  $this->db->from('product_sub_category3');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
   } */
}

?>
```

in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
             $this->load->helper('url');
             $this->load->model('homemodel');

$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url()."index.php/welcome/index";
$total_row = $this->homemodel->record_count();
$config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
$config["per_page"] =1;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] =2;
$config['cur_tag_open'] ='&nbsp;<a class="current">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
if($this->uri->segment(3)){
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
}
else{
$page = 1;
}
$data["results"] = $this->homemodel->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

// View data according to array.
$this->load->view("home", $data);                  
    }
```

Comment: increase this `$config['num_links'] =2;`

Comment: i increased but not working fine

Comment: `$this->homemodel->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);` here the `$page` is the 3rd uri segment which should be used as the `$offset` as answered by another user. but in your model class, you are receiving as `$id` and retrieving a row whose `id` is that value. That is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
$data['links'] = $str_links;
```

in your view just do `echo $links;`.

let me know if it works.

Comment: after doing i got this error,                                                                        A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/home.php

Line Number: 65

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\etrade\application\views\home.php
Line: 65
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\etrade\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 39
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\etrade\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: as far as i know `$this->pagination->create_links();` returns a string. Please refer to the documentation here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: but in my view  this echo code is working fine                                                                           <ul class = "pagination">
    <?php foreach ($links as $link) {
echo "<li>". $link."</li>";

} ?>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give offset alongwith limit to fetch records.

```
$this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
```

and remove this line `$this->db->where('id', $id);`

`$offset` will the from which point next record to fetch. eg: 1-20, 21-40 etc.

Comment: $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3): 0);

Comment: and pass that `$offset` in the function you are fetching records in controller. In model add $this->db->limit($limit,$offset); and remove condition of ID.

Comment: code is working in 1st page it displaying 1-20 products its fine but 2nd page it displaying 3-22 products,in 3 page it displaying 4-23 products so on,why so?

Comment: use this in model : `$this->db->limit($offset,$limit);` and in controller, add `$offset = $limit * $page` . eg: $offset = 20 * 1 , 20*2 etc.

Comment: use this as $page, 
`$page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3): 0);`

Comment: the changes i made  as u said                                                        $config['per_page']=20;        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3): 0);
$offset = $config['per_page'] * $page;
$data["results"] = $this->homemodel->fetch_data($offset,$config['per_page']);                                                        i'm getting output 1-20 in first page,41-60 in second page ,61-80 in third page so on

Comment: change `$offset = $limit *($page -1);` and check.

Comment: i changed $offset = $limit *($page -1); in query limit will be like limit(0,20), limit(20,20),limit(40,20) and so on,but then also i'm not getting output.why?

Comment: i changed code In model $this->db->limit($limit,$offset); , i got output ,thanks Mayoori

Comment: sorry, by mistake i exchanged the place of $limit and $offset. I didnot noticed it.

Comment: And also I changed $page = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3): 1);

Comment: Ok. I mentioned that in my old comments, but placement of $offset got changed.Finally issue got resolved. That's important.